# How to zoom in the Y-Axis in a line chart using kibana 7.12/7.16

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

I'm working on an application that get values from different cryptocurrency exchanges and I'm trying to plot that values on Kibana (V 7.12.1) to visually compare the oscillations, everything is working fine (I think), the main application is getting the values from the exchanges and sending to ElasticSearch (V 7.12.1) and I can see the values on Kibana/Discover. I don't have much experience on ElasticSearch/Kibana.

So, in Kibana, I created a new dashboard with a Lens panel, I added the DateTime field to X-axis, ask price and bid price to Y-axis and the exchange name as a break down. The plot looks nice as you can see:

[image]

The problem is, at this moment, the values are between 42940 and 43080, a very small difference comparing to the total size of the Y-axis and I can not adjust the Y-axis to get a small window to only see the values of interest.

I don't need different scales to each line, in really it must be the same scale. And values will change over the time, so, the value window will change in size too.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I did all the same tests on ElasticSearch 7.16.3 and Kibana 7.16.3 and I got exact the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it.

There is an Up-Down button to set up the Y-axis, clicking on that button we get the window "Left axis". In that window, the field "Bounds" does this adjust.

- Full: to see all the graph;
- Data bounds: to automatically adjust the zoom;
- Custom: to insert your own limits;

[image]